# Embedding another web portal inside our application

Tags: spring, servlets, web, portlet

I need some pointers for embedding an external web portal inside our web application. our web application is built on struts, spring framework. We need to integrate an external tool with our application. We need to pass certain parameters to that external tool and handle the response as well. There requirement is to show external web portal screen inside our application. How can we achieve this?

Could anyone please provide pointers on this?